# Exibir rótulo de dados em gráfico de linha no ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, gráfico

Tenho um gráfico de linhas e gostaria de por o rótulo do estado correspondente à linha, mas está saindo o rótulo em cada dado disponível e não somente o último:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Código que estou ulizando:

```
library(tidyverse)

dados <- read_delim("~/Downloads/arquivo_geral.csv", 
                    ";", escape_double = FALSE, trim_ws = TRUE)
dados <- dados[,-1]

dados %>%
  filter(casosAcumulados > 9) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = data, y = log(casosAcumulados), col = estado)) +
  geom_line() +
  geom_text(aes(label = estado), 
            vjust = -1) +
  theme(legend.box = "none") +
  ggtitle("Casos confirmados - Brasil", "(Em log)")
```

Base de dados: https://covid.saude.gov.br/

Comment: Olha, só porque não entendi a dúvida direito. Você quer por o rótulo no último ponto disponível em cada linha?

Comment: Sim, e esse ponto representando o estado.

Comment: Todos os pontos terminam na mesma data? Se sim acho que botar `geom_text(aes(label = estado, x = ultima_data_da_sua_tabela), 
            vjust = -1) `

Comment: Se as datas forem diferentes você pode ou antes fazer um vetor com as datas ou mudar os dados do texto geom_text(data = . %>% group_by(estado) %>% filter(data== max(data)), aes(label = estado), vjust = -1)

Comment: Eu só trocaria o log da quantidade (que se entende menos) por uma escala logaritmica `meu_grafico + scale_y_log10()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]Uma opção é você criar um objeto com as posições dos estados no último dia dos seus dados:

```
nm_estados <- dados %>% 
   filter(data == max(data))
```

E depois usar esse objeto na plotagem, como fonte dos nomes:

```
dados %>%
   filter(casosAcumulados > 9) %>%
   ggplot(aes(x = data, y = log(casosAcumulados), col = estado)) +
   geom_line() +
   geom_text(aes(label = estado), check_overlap = T, data = nm_estados,
             vjust = -1) +
   theme(legend.box = "none") +
   ggtitle("Casos confirmados - Brasil", "(Em log)")
```